# Codenameone, apple rejected my app

Tags: codenameone

I'm new here, and I hope you could help me.

I've developed a codenameone app built to iOS which works fine on the simulator. I submmited to apple but they rejected with this message:

"Specifically, we found the username and password fields to be unresponsive. Please refer to the attached screenshot."

The first view is a login form, username and password.

the code codenameone used is:

@Override

```
protected void onMain_BtnEntrarAction(final Component c, ActionEvent event) {

    String usuario = findTxtUsuario().getText().trim();
    String password = findTxtPassword().getText().trim();

    if (usuario.compareTo("") == 0 || password.compareTo("") == 0) {
        Dialog.show("Ecobiocar SAS", "Ingrese Usuario y Contraseña", "OK", null);
    } else {

        ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest() {
            Hashtable h;
            boolean valido = false;

            @Override
            protected void postResponse() {
                valido = Boolean.valueOf(h.get("success").toString());
                if (valido) {
                    Storage.getInstance().writeObject("usuario", h);
                    showForm("Servicios", null);
                } else {
                    Dialog.show("Ecobiocar SAS", "Usuario NO Válido", "OK", null);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
                h = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));
            }
        };
        cr.setUrl("https://www.domainname.com/dirname/servletName");
        cr.setPost(true);
        cr.addArgument("task", "1");
        cr.addArgument("usrname", usuario);
        cr.addArgument("password", password);
        InfiniteProgress prog = new InfiniteProgress();
        Dialog dlg = prog.showInifiniteBlocking();
        cr.setDisposeOnCompletion(dlg);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(cr);

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So can you show us the attached screenshot or is it irrelevant?

Comment: When you say "Built to iOS", does that mean you tried it out on an iOS device before submitting it to the app store?  If not, always do that.  It is possible that iOS blocking the network connection due to an invalid SSL certificate.  They're really picky on the level of support for SSL that a server has.   If you test on iOS device, and it works, that would rule out this as a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing domainname.com isn't the real domain and doesn't have a standard certificate as Steve mentioned Apple is very picky about SSL/Certificates.